# The path environment variable is different depending on where I open cmd

Tags: cmd, environment-variables

I have an annoying problem where my path environment variable is not correctly updated in new cmd instances.

If I update my path variable and open a new cmd in some folder, the path variable is not updated until i restart my PC. However, I noticed that it IS updated if I open a cmd directly (shift right click open) on my desktop. I have found a workaround using the refresh option in [pathmgr](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Batch-Script-To-Manage-7d0ef21e), but I find it very curious that the variable is correctly updated in some places but not others.

If someone knows a permanent fix for my problem, or simply why the path variable is updated in my desktop folder but not elsewhere, I would love to hear it. I'm on Windows 7, 64-bit.

Comment: If a new cmd is opened from the destop, it will have the environment from the system registry. It does not matter what has been done in other cmd shells. If `pathmgr` is used to change the registry, then a new cmd shell will have the new settings.